# How to get data from queryResult->getFulfillmentMessages() Dialogflow v2

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am using the google/cloud-dialogflow library for php.

I can not get the data from `$queryResult->getFulfillmentMessages()`; I don't know how.

I have tried:

```
json_decode($queryResult->getFulfillmentMessages()->serializeToJsonString(), true);
```

But it shows me a error. I hope you can help me.

[image]

Comment: Have you examined the contents of either `$queryResult` or `$queryResult->getFulfillmentMessages()`? If so, can you update your question to include them? Can you update your question to show any sample code of what you're trying to do? Finally, please don't post images of code or text - just put them in the question and use the formatting in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me. The response that is received from the queryResult is a protobuf repeated field. The payload that is required to be extracted can be accessed by calling the first element of the repeated field and serializing it to JSON string then decoding it.

```
    json_decode($queryResult->getFulfillmentMessages()[0]->serializeToJsonString(), true);
```

This will give the payload in array format using which you can perform your operations on it.